# 500 error after uploading web config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

Having some issues after uploading my web.config file on to my hosting server. 123.reg is my hosting provider.

I have placed the following web config into my root folder unfortunately I now receive a 500 error on the server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <location path="wordpress">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
          <clear/>
          <add ipAddress="###.###.###.###"/>
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://carltonmotorhomes.co.uk" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
      <!-- 301 permanent redirect -->
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://carltonmotorhomes.co.uk" httpResponseStatus="Found" />
      <!-- 302 found redirect -->
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://carltonmotorhomes.co.uk" httpResponseStatus="Temporary" />
      <!-- 307 temporary redirect -->
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://carltonmotorhomes.co.uk" exactDestination="true" />
      <!-- 302 (found) redirect, to a specific page or directory -->
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

So as you can see I am trying to ensure access is restricted to the 'wordpress' folder unless  ip address matches and trying to handle 300 errors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error could be caused by modifying `<ipSecurity>` in web.config, by default this section is locked at the server level and does not allow site level modification.

You may refer to [scenario 7 in this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx) for solutions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTTP Redirection is not available on the default installation of IIS 7. (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) You probably have it installed locally but not on the production server.

If you have access to the server you can install it, but if you don't your best solution would be to create an HttpModule to handle the redirects.